# JSON null value using opt()

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on a API that has a bad design by putting `null` value on some item that originally holds double/float value. Now I thought there must be a short solution where I do not need to make tons of if else statement just to check if a value is null which seems to be done by using `optDouble("key", fallback_value)` but the error still hits whenever a field value is null.

Stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at median_tx_value of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to double
```

I tried to check the source code of method

```
/**
     * Returns the value mapped by {@code name} if it exists and is a double or
     * can be coerced to a double, or {@code fallback} otherwise.
     */
    public double optDouble(@Nullable String name, double fallback) {
        Object object = opt(name);
        Double result = JSON.toDouble(object);
        return result != null ? result : fallback;
    }
```

It seems the error starts at `JSON.toDouble(object)` where object is null already. Is there any way to achieved it without using third party library?

Comment: why not use `try/catch` & catch specifically that `JSONException ` & then either assign a default value to your variable at start or in the `catch` block?

Comment: @DarShan as I stated I do not want to make a lot of if else statement just for this matter since the code is already that long due to a lot of data crawled from each JSON object. Also I do not know which/when a value becomes null, maybe today non null fields has value but what if the next day it becomes null as well it will cost too much trouble just for that. It is very unpredictable since we do not own this API.

Comment: It is in a try catch since it is mandatory when working on a JSON but who knows when other field becomes null as well, we can't catch all field as it will be a very long code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my temporary solution for now, feel free to improve.

```
private double optionalDouble(JSONObject object, String key){

        if (!object.isNull(key)) {
            try {
                return object.getDouble(key);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0.0;
            }
        }
        else
            return 0.0;

    }
```